# How do i make a code that keeps an artificial time?

Tags: python

I'm making a code in python that measures time in D&D, but the its not keeping the time accurately and will sometimes give the time with a bunch of zeros after the seconds, also i cant get the am pm feature to work.

```
import time

hour=int(input("how many seonds is one hour in your D&D?"))
minutes = hour/60
hour_time=10
day_time="Am"
minutes_time=0.00
true = 1
while true == 1:
    time.sleep (minutes)
    if hour_time==12 and minutes_time==0:
        if day_time=="Am":
            day_time="Pm"
        else:
            day_time="Am"
    if minutes_time>0.59:
        minutes_time = 0
        if hour_time==12: 
            hour_time = 1
        else:
            hour_time = hour_time + 1
    else:
        minutes_time = minutes_time + 0.01
    print(minutes_time+hour_time,"",day_time)
```

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow! What do you mean by accurately? What is your expected result?

Comment: Is it normal that you ask the user for seconds and that you store that in the `hour` variable?

Comment: Is it normal that you use `minutes` as seconds for `sleep()`?

Comment: @Tim `hour` represents the amount of seconds for 1 hour, and `minutes` represents the amount of seconds for 1 minute (for what I understood) so sleeping that amount to increase the D&D time by 1 minute seems normal

Comment: Ok i didn't get the original goal of the code at first sight. Thanks @Rafalon.

Comment: @Tim yeah, it could have been named `seconds_per_hour` and `seconds_per_minute` instead

Comment: Please *mark* the answers as accepted if it answers your question @FreeButtPlugs.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you sometime get lots of zeroes is a formatting problem. You can specify a format to numbers in Python, just as in:

```
print("{:.2f}".format(minutes_time+hour_time),"",day_time)
```

Before:

```
10.33  Am
10.34  Am
10.35  Am
10.36  Am
10.370000000000001  Am
10.38  Am
10.39  Am
10.4  Am
```

After:

```
10.16  Am
10.17  Am
10.18  Am
10.19  Am
10.20  Am
10.21  Am
10.22  Am
10.23  Am
10.24  Am
10.25  Am
10.26  Am
```

Please note that over the running period of your program a precision error propagates when accumulating in `minutes_time = minutes_time + 0.01`.
Floats have computing precision limits you can get rid of using Python's `fractions.Fraction` for example.

Here is a working example of your code that uses `Fraction`:

```
import time
from fractions import Fraction

hour=int(input("how many seonds is one hour in your D&D?"))
minutes = hour/60
hour_time=10
day_time="Am"
minutes_time=Fraction(0, 1)
true = 1
while true == 1:
    time.sleep (minutes)
    if hour_time==12 and minutes_time==0:
        if day_time=="Am":
            day_time="Pm"
        else:
            day_time="Am"
    if minutes_time>=Fraction(59, 100):
        minutes_time = 0
        if hour_time==12: 
            hour_time = 1
        else:
            hour_time = hour_time + 1
    else:
        minutes_time = minutes_time + Fraction(1, 100)
    print("{:.2f}".format(float(minutes_time)+hour_time),"",day_time)
```

Comment: Note that it seems to be a bit more than a formatting issue. The fact that adding 59 times `0.01` to `0.00` leads to `0.59[0000000000001]` being `>0.59` is quite disturbing to me.

Comment: @Rafalon Just as you cannot represent `1/3` precisely as a  base 10 (i.e. decimal) number, you cannot represent `.01` precisely as a binary (or hexadecimal) number, which is usually the underlying base of floating point numbers. So take an approximate representation and magnify that error 59-fold and you cannot expect too much.  This is *very* basic stuff.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Yes, I understand that, which is why I would play with integers when dealing with hours / minutes / seconds (and therefore replace that `> 0.59` with `> 58`)

Comment: @RonaldAaronson not in floats, but with fractions. Rafalon is right.

Comment: @tim I think Rafalon's comment could have been better expressed.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson you're right. What bothers me is that the *logic* behind `if minutes_time>0.59` is wrong (should be `0.58`), but it works only because of precision error

Comment: @Rafalon Who said two wrongs don't make a right? Oh the irony!

Comment: You're both right :) What do you think about my Fraction-based code?

Comment: Seems good except from the fact you changed the formatting to 3 digits for some reason ;)

Comment: Golden-eye @Rafalon. Fixed.